# Symbol for dyadic rationals

Tags: notation, terminology, rational-numbers

Set of integers is denoted by the symbol $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q[x]$ stands for univariate polynomials over rationals, etc.

Is there a symbol which indicates the set of dyadic rationals?

Comment: Not that I've ever seen. Just make one up and make sure you say what it means. $\Bbb D$? $\Bbb Q_2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there is a widespread symbol. Your best bet is to just define your terms, e.g. 'let $D$ denote the set of all dyadic rational numbers'.

The dyadic rationals are the localisation of $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to the powers of $2$ (or equivalently by the set $\{ 2 \}$), and also the free $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra generated by the set $\{ 2^{-n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, so any of the following will do:
$$\mathbb{Z}[2^{-1}], \quad \{ 2 \}^{-1} \mathbb{Z}, \quad \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle 2x-1 \rangle, \quad \mathbb{Z} \langle \{ 2^{-n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} \rangle$$